# How do I access array members in a Knockout component in a foreach?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having trouble getting a Knockout component to work - i can't seem to get it to bind properly to the members of an array on my ViewModel during a `foreach` accessed using `$index`.

In [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayseeare/87ys0hu0/) you will see what I mean.

There are two little view Models:

```
function OtherThingViewModel(thingString){
   this.thingString = ko.observable(thingString);
}

function ThingViewModel(thingNumber, thing){
    this.thingNumber = ko.observable(thingNumber);
}
```

Instances are created in the main viewModel:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    this.things = [ 
        new ThingViewModel(1),
        new ThingViewModel(2),
        new ThingViewModel(3)
    ];

    this.otherThings = [ 
        new OtherThingViewModel("a Thing"),
        new OtherThingViewModel("another Thing"),
        new OtherThingViewModel("some Thing")
    ];

    this.specialThing = ko.unwrap(this.things)[0];
    this.specialOtherThing = ko.unwrap(this.otherThings)[0];
};
```

Then I have a component:

```
ko.components.register('combinedthing-component', {
    template:
    '<div>'
    + ' <h3 data-bind="text: \'Thing \' + thing.thingNumber()"></h3>'
    + ' <p>'
    + '     <label>thingNumber: <input data-bind="value: thing.thingNumber" /></label>'
    + '     <span data-bind="text: thing.thingNumber" />'
    + ' </p>'
    + ' <p>'
    + '     <label>thingString: <input data-bind="value: otherThing.thingString" /></label>'
    + '     <span data-bind="text: otherThing.thingString" />'
    + ' </p>'
    + ' <p data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.unwrap(otherThing))"></p>'
    + '</div>'
});
```

for displaying data from the two view models.

In the HTML I can successfully use the the component and using a `foreach` I can combine the two objects:

```
<h1>1 component</h1>
<combinedthing-component params="thing: specialThing, otherThing: specialOtherThing"></combinedthing-component>

<h1>Foreach</h1>
<!-- ko foreach: things -->
    <div>
        <h3 data-bind="text: 'Thing ' + thingNumber()"></h3>
        <p>
            <label>thingNumber <Input data-bind="value: thingNumber" /></label>
            <span data-bind="text: thingNumber" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>thingString: <input data-bind="value: $root.otherThings[$index()].thingString" /></label>
            <span data-bind="text: $root.otherThings[$index()].thingString" />
        </p>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

but if I try and combine the two - looping thorugh `things` with the `foreach` and then accessing the `otherThings` Array using $index and binding these to the component:

```
<h1>Many Components</h1>
<!-- ko foreach: things -->
    <combinedthing-component params="thing: $data, otherThing: $root.otherThings[$index()]"></combinedthing-component>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then while I get an object in `otherThing` (as proved by the ko.toJSON binding) its properties are not binding to the `input` and `span`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to how params are passed into a component when using the "web component" syntax. The objects passed through `params=""` get transformed into dependent observables (computeds). Behind the scenes, `$root.otherThings[$index()]` essentially becomes a computed observable with this implementation `function () { return $root.otherThings[$index()]; }`.

The simplest way is to get what you want is to add a `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` when referencing `otherThing`. This will ensure that you're always working with the actual `otherThing` instead of an observable wrapping it.

```
<label>thingString: <input data-bind="value: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(otherThing).thingString" /></label>
<span data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(otherThing).thingString" />
```

The ideal place to do this unwrapping would be in view model part of the component registration.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87ys0hu0/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the input! is there any reason not to use `ko.unwrap` here? i think the two are interchangeable do you know if is that right?

Comment: Depends on what version of Knockout you are using. Older versions only had `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`. The newer way, `ko.unwrap` is basically just a shortcut to the same function.