# How do I bind in nested knockout components using web-component markup?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I really want to use nested `web-component` style markup, but I can never seem to get it to work.  I have it working because of the note [here (in the answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441503/how-do-i-access-array-members-in-a-knockout-component-in-a-foreach):

> The problem is due to how params are passed into a component when using the "web component" syntax.

I don't really understand what they are saying, and the OP is dealing with arrays.  I understand that it creates computed observables out of things.  But `params` in my constructor of the nested component is always `$raw` and nothing.

```
<parent-component>
  <content>
    <!--works-->
    <div data-bind="component: { name: 'child-component', params: { id: $parent.id } }"></div>

    <!-- does not work -->
    <child-component params="id: '{{$parent.id}}'"></child-component>

  </content>
</parent-component>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m7ckyzo/1/)

Why can't I nest `web-component` style knockout components and have binding work?

Comment: Could you extend your sample code into an [mcve]?

Comment: I will do this as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, kudos to @Jeroen for making me provide a better example.

My issue was that I was wrapping the parameter in single quotes and using `{{handle bars}}` for the binding.  once I removed those it seems to be working fine.

```
    <!-- does not work -->
    <child-component params="id: '{{$parent.id}}'"></child-component>

    <!-- wow, this does work! -->
    <child-component params="id: $parent.id"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of web components here https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp

Typical main html with components:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2>Three Component View Model Binding Test</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- THE GOAL OF THE PROJECT IS TO BIND EVERYTHING BEFORE AND AFTER THE FOLLOWING COMPONENT WITH centralViewModel -->
                <!-- ###ko stopBinding: true -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <component-one></component-one>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <component-two></component-two>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <component-three></component-three>
                </div>
                <!-- ###/ko -->

                <p>Note: if component one did not load above, then check your browser console for errors</p>
            </div>
```

a typical component - note it is written in ES2015 (New Javascript)

```
const ko = require('knockout')
        , CentralData = require('../../service-providers/central-data')
        , CentralState = require('../../service-providers/central-state')
        , template = require('./template.html');

    const viewModel = function (data) {

        //Make service providers accessible to data-bind and templates
        this.CentralData = CentralData;
        this.CentralState = CentralState;

        this.componentName = 'Component One';
        this.foo = ko.observable(`${this.componentName} Foo`);
        this.bar = ko.observableArray(this.componentName.split(' '));
        this.barValue = ko.observable("");
        this.bar.push('bar');
        this.addToBar = (stuffForBar) => {
            if(this.barValue().length >= 1) {
                this.bar.push(this.barValue());
                CentralData.pushMoreData({firstName: this.componentName,secondName:this.barValue()});
            }
        };
        this.CentralState.signIn(this.componentName);
        if (CentralData.dataWeRetrieved().length < 10) {
            var dataToPush = {firstName : this.componentName, secondName : 'Foo-Bar'};
            CentralData.pushMoreData(dataToPush);
        }
    };
    console.info('Component One Running');
    module.exports = {
        name: 'component-one',
        viewModel: viewModel,
        template: template
    };
```

template.html:

```
    <div>
        <h1 data-bind="text: componentName"></h1>
        <p>Foo is currently: <span data-bind="text: foo"></span></p>
        <p>Bar is an array. It's values currently are:</p>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: bar">
            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
        </ul>
        <form data-bind="submit: addToBar">
            <input type="text"
                   name="bar"
                   placeholder="Be witty!"
                   data-bind="attr: {id : componentName}, value : barValue" />
            <button type="submit">Add A Bar</button>
        </form>
        <h2>Central State</h2>
        <p>The following components are currently signed in to Central State Service Provider</p>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: CentralState.signedInComponents()">
            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Central Data</h2>
        <p>The following information is available from Central Data Service Provider</p>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Component Name</th><th>Second Value</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: CentralData.dataWeRetrieved -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td><td data-bind="text: secondName"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </table>
        <h3>End of Component One!</h3>
    </div>
```

app.js has the component bindings

```
const ko = require('knockout');

/**
 * The modules that follow are singleton modules that do not appear to conflict with bindings
 *
 */

const CentralData = require('./service-providers/central-data');   // Mock centralised data/model service
const CentralState = require('./service-providers/central-state'); // Mock centralised state service

/**
 * Register knockout web components - these work, but conflict with any central bindings
 */

ko.components.register(
    'component-one',
    require('./components/component-one/component.js')
);

ko.components.register(
    'component-two',
    require('./components/component-two/component.js')
);

ko.components.register(
    'component-three',
    require('./components/component-three/component.js')
);

/**
 * This code comes from http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html
 *
 * Telling Knockout to Skip Binding Part of a Page
 *
 * However, when used around a component, the component does not load/run!
 *
 */

ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;


/**
 * centralViewModel should be loadable for "all of the page not managed by components"
 *
 * That is the goal of the project, which I am failing in badly at the moment
 *
 */

const centralViewModel = {
    bindingWorked : ko.observable('The binding worked. KO view model centralViewModel has a this context and was bound to the html correctly')
};

console.info('app.js applying bindings...');

/**
 * The next line should bind central viewmodel to everything, but conflicts with components!!
 */

ko.applyBindings(centralViewModel,document.body);

// ko.applyBindings(); // Pull in all of the components


/**
Note: to avoid binding issues, we should be able to add these html comments around each component
 <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
 <component-name>
 <!-- /ko -->
 However - when we do, the components no longer work
 */
```

Comment: I don't see any nested components that use the `web component` style markup though... that is my issue.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `<component-two></component-two>` for example were what you were after.

Comment: nested is the key for me, one component inside another, both with custom markup inside the component.

Comment: If you use the custom component method, you can nest as many as you like. Each component would call up the next one. The hard thing for me was getting ko binding to work on the rest of the page outside the knockout components without clashing with the internal bindings

Comment: Binding context can be difficult sometimes.  I also use qtip for some fly outs and have to bind when it opens, but you have to be careful because KO doesn't let you bind multiple times to the same markup.  Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: No worries - I will refactor my example to include nested components and off component binding.